# Multiline equation number

Tags: equations, amsmath

I have a multiline equation like:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\label{equation label here}
\begin{gathered}
someEquationRightHere \\
moreEquationHere \\
andEvenMoreHere
\end{gathered}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

And it gets rendered to:

[image: Rendering]

I would like the number (2) to be at the last line of the equation (just as it shows to the right, but in line with `andEvenMoreHere`). I heard that `\usepackage[tbtags]{amsmath}` should do it, but I use it in my code to no avail.

How could I make the equation numbers appear in last lines of the equation, rather than in the middle?

Comment: The `tbtags` option applies only to the `split` environment.  Indeed, the _User’s Guide for the `amsmath` Package_ could state this more clearly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest is to add the optional`[b]`argument with `gathered`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \label{equation label here}
  \begin{gathered}[b]
    \text{someEquationRightHere} \\
    \text{moreEquationHere} \\
    \text{andEvenMoreHere}
  \end{gathered}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways. For example, the equations can be set in the numbered environment `gather`, but with disabled numbers for the first two equations:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
\text{someEquationRightHere}\nonumber\\
\text{moreEquationHere}\nonumber\\
\label{equation label here}
\text{andEvenMoreHere}
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]